# badge en layout de razor page

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

de antemano, les agradezco la ayuda brindada.
Mi consulta es como modificar el badge que tengo en mi layout-razor?
Estaba usando viewcomponent, pero el problema es que necesito hacer un submit para que se vea reflejado los cambios.
supongo que debo usar ajax para que no se refresque la pagina, pero el problema es que no se como acceder a mi layout sin viewcomponents o partial view.
Este es mi layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Zigma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link href="~/css/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">
                    <img src="~/images/Logo.png" style="width:110px;" />
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Loguin">Registrar/Ingresar</a>
                        </li>
                        <vc:badge-count></vc:badge-count>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - WebDelivery - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("Styles", false);
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos bro, edita la pregunta, agrega la estructura que tienes en tu proyecto junto con los controladores y los ViewComponents, recuerda que tienes que colocar los elementos de tu escenario para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducirlo sin problemas. Enlaces recomendados: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por la ayuda, pero tengo una duda, no se si usar viewcomponents, ya que este me obliga a hacer un submit para que se refleje mis cambios. Por eso pregunto si habría otra forma, quizas con ajax para que la pagina no tenga que estar refrescando.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta era muy sencilla y obvia, Por mas que el badge estuviera en un layout, yo podía llamarlo ya que a las finales ese layout forma parte de todos los formularios que uso.
Asi que un simple codigo como este me funciono :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <button id="butonpopover" type="button" class="btn btn-link nav-link" data-toggle="popover" data-content="carrito de compras bichaaaas"><span class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-lg" style="color:dodgerblue"></span><span id="badgecount" class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">@Model.Sum(p => p.Cantidad)</span></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

$('#badgecount').text(listaItem.sum("Cantidad"));